# Animate Values while scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, jquery-animate

i'm working on a simple one-page website. You can navigate by clicking on links inside a fixed navigation. This fixed navigation should work like seen here: http://www.teehanlax.com/story/medium/

Something like Tehann / Lax does (fixed navigation, which only shows when you scroll up and disappears when you scroll down) i could probably do on my own. But i want to modify this example a bit, so it works like seen on this website: 
http://nzopera.com/2013/don-giovanni

On this example the navigation works like on Tehann / Lax Website, but different. It not only animates, but appears / disappears but it reacts to your scrolling. I think it's best to have a look at the last page i wrote down here to understand my intention. How can i achieve an effect like this? I know how to detect whether you scroll up or down, see my current code. But i'm not sure at all about animating depending on your scroll position.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Please check my answer to this post, i tried to describe what i need a bit more in detail.

**EDIT:** This is what i got so far, but that is just with normal jQuery animations

```
$(function(){
    var
        scrollTop = 0,
        lastScrollTop = 0, 
        delta = 50;

    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

        if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - scrollTop) <= delta)
            return;

        if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop){
            if($(".header").hasClass("header--active")) $(".header").removeClass("header--active").animate({ top : -84 });
        } else {
            if(!$(".header").hasClass("header--active")) $(".header").addClass("header--active").animate({ top : 0 });
        }
        lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
    });
});
```

Comment: http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Comment: Thanks, but does this plugin work for my example? As far as i have seen you have to use data attributes for the scrolling animations, but i need to do it dynamically in JS: Slide Navigation down (show), when scrolling up ... What i basically need is a JS function to animate values, so something like:

function linearMovement(startValue, endValue, time/distance in px);

So to animate a CSS value from 0 to 80 in 200px the jQuery Code would look like $("element").css("width", linearMovement(0, 80, 200));

Does something like this exist or is this possible to do with jQuery / JS?

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged jQuery, you can display the text on the event the user scrolls

Something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
  //do stuff here 
 });
```

If you want to make it appear at a certain point like the navigation on the site you linked, just create a flag like below example:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var ypos = window.pageYOffset;
var scroll_pos = 200;             

if(ypos > scroll_pos) {
    //do stuff here
}
});
```

See here for more details: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: I know that and i know, how to detect whether you scroll up or down. I'm not trying to display text on scrolling, but i want to show the fixed navigation when i scroll up and hide, when i scroll down again. Just scroll down a bit on this page http://nzopera.com/2013/don-giovanni and then scroll up. You will notice that the navigation animates in. 
This is just the basic stuff, but i'm not sure, how to create that effect with the fixed navigation, you can see in the example link above.

Comment: Thanks, but i think i haven't described in detail what i need. I tried to explain it a bit more in my answer to the first post. I'm looking for the slide Up / Down effect you see in my example link. Its not just jQuery slideUp and SlideDown but it reacts to your scrolling. Therefore i need a function to animate values (see my answer to the first post).